# I'm getting error every time I'm calling withdraw function from treasury contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, inheritance

```
//Treasury.sol
SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "./Lending.sol";
contract Treasury is Lending{

Lending lending = new Lending();
bool internal checkEligibility;
uint public eligibleAmt;
event receiveFundEvent(
uint  indexed  amount);
event withdrawEvent(
address  indexed borrower,
uint indexed amount);
uint totalFund = 0;

function receiveFund() payable public  {
uint amt = lending.calculateInterest();
require(msg.value==amt,"Repay The correct Amount");
totalFund = msg.value + totalFund;
emit receiveFundEvent(msg.value);}

function withdraw (uint  _collateralVal) public {
eligibleAmt = super.requestForLoan( _collateralVal);
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(eligibleAmt);
   totalFund = totalFund -eligibleAmt;
   emit withdrawEvent(msg.sender,eligibleAmt);}



   function fakeFund() public payable {}
```

}

Error:
revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `payable` modifier in the `withdraw` function like below:

```
function withdraw(unit _collateralVal) public payable {
   // Your code...
}
```

More information about `payable` keyword: https://solidity-fr.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/cheatsheet.html#modifiers